# navigation destination issue with environment object

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, environment-variables, swift-data

I am currently working on a study app and have encountered an issue. I am using swift data to store my 'events' and I am using a navigation destination to allow users to edit said  'events' however I am also using user notifications. I am using an environment object in my EditEventView to pass through my Local Notifications manager. when adding this environment object I get the following error in EventView:

> Cannot convert value of type '(SwiftDataModel, EnvironmentObject, Environment) -> EditEventView' to expected argument type '(SwiftDataModel) -> EditEventView'

Just wondering if anyone has encountered a similar issue and/or have a solution!

EventView:

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData
import UserNotifications

struct EventView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @Query var events: [SwiftDataModel]
    @State private var path = [SwiftDataModel]()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            List {
                ForEach(events) { event in
                    NavigationLink(value: event) {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                Text(event.nameOfSession)
                                    .font(.headline)
                                Text(event.date.formatted(date: .long, time: .shortened))
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteDistractions)
                .listRowBackground(Color(.systemGray6))
            }
            .onAppear {
                        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { success, error in
                            if success {
                                print ("All Set!")
                            } else if let error = error {
                                print(error.localizedDescription)
                            }
                        }
                    }
            .background(.white)
            .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
            .navigationTitle("Your Sessions")
//error 
            **.navigationDestination(for: SwiftDataModel.self, destination: EditEventView.init)** 
            .toolbar {
                Button{
                    addDistraction()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    //MARK: Swift Data model functions
    
    // Add study session data to model
    
    func addDistraction() {
        let event = SwiftDataModel()
        modelContext.insert(event)
        path = [event]
    }
    
    // Delete study session data from model
    
    func deleteDistractions( indexSet: IndexSet) {
        for index in indexSet {
            let event = events[index]
            modelContext.delete(event)
            }
        }
}

#Preview {
    EventView()
}
```

EditEventView:

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct EditEventView: View {
    @Bindable var event: SwiftDataModel
    @EnvironmentObject var lnManager: LocalNotificationManager
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form {
                TextField("Name", text: $event.name_of_event)
                
                Picker("Work recording metheod", selection: $event.subject_type) {
                    Text ("Other").tag(EventType.other)
                    Text ("English").tag(EventType.english)
                    Text ("Humanities").tag(EventType.humanities)
                    Text ("Maths").tag(EventType.maths)
                    Text ("Sciance").tag(EventType.sciance)
                    
                }
                .pickerStyle(.menu)
                
                DatePicker("Session Date", selection: $event.event_date)
                    .datePickerStyle(CompactDatePickerStyle())
                    .frame(maxHeight: 400)
                
                Toggle("Notifications", isOn: $event.is_notified)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Add Session")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .onAppear {
                event.date = Date.now
            }
            Button{
                if event.is_notified {
                    Task {
                        let dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: event.event_date)
                        let localNotification = LocalNotification(identifier: UUID().uuidString, title: "Its study time!", body: "Looks like your studying \(event.subject_type.rawValue)", repeats: false, dateComponents: dateComponents)
                        await lnManager.schedule(localNotification: localNotification)
                    }
                }
            } label: {
                Text ("Add Event")
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `EditEventView(event: event)` takes an event parameter.
 Your code does not have that in your `.navigationDestination(...)`.

Comment: Look at the first code sample in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationstack), I think it’s something like that you need to use.